# How to run multiple instances of a single object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, physics

Currently attempting to make a physics simulation for elastic collisions of circles. I am having an issue where I do not know how to run the simulation with two circles interacting at the same time. I am not yet looking to create the interaction between the circles just to have them both running simultaneously. Any help is much appreciated. This is my first post so I apologize if I formatted something incorrectly.

```js
var width = 400;
var height = 400;
var canvas = ctx = false;
var frameRate = 1 / 60; // Seconds
var frameDelay = frameRate * 1000; // ms
var loopTimer = false;
var ball = {
  position: {
    x: width / 2,
    y: height / 2
  },
  velocity: {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  },
  radius: 15, // 1px = 1cm
  restitution: -1
};
var mouse = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  isDown: false
};

function getMousePosition(event) {
  mouse.x = event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  mouse.y = event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
}
var mouseDown = function(event) {
  if (event.which == 1) {
    getMousePosition(event);
    mouse.isDown = true;
    ball.position.x = mouse.x;
    ball.position.y = mouse.y;
  }
}
var mouseUp = function(event) {
  if (event.which == 1) {
    mouse.isDown = false;
    ball.velocity.y = (ball.position.y - mouse.y) / 10;
    ball.velocity.x = (ball.position.x - mouse.x) / 10;
  }
}
var setup = function() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.onmousemove = getMousePosition;
  canvas.onmousedown = mouseDown;
  canvas.onmouseup = mouseUp;
  ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
  loopTimer = setInterval(loop, frameDelay);
}
var loop = function() {
  if (!mouse.isDown) {
    ball.position.x += ball.velocity.x * frameRate * 100;
    ball.position.y += ball.velocity.y * frameRate * 100;
  }
  if (ball.position.y > height - ball.radius) {
    ball.velocity.y *= ball.restitution;
    ball.position.y = height - ball.radius;
  }
  if (ball.position.x > width - ball.radius) {
    ball.velocity.x *= ball.restitution;
    ball.position.x = width - ball.radius;
  }
  if (ball.position.x < ball.radius) {
    ball.velocity.x *= ball.restitution;
    ball.position.x = ball.radius;
  }
  if (ball.position.y < ball.radius) {
    ball.velocity.y *= ball.restitution;
    ball.position.y = ball.radius;
  }
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(ball.position.x, ball.position.y);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, ball.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.restore();
  if (mouse.isDown) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(ball.position.x, ball.position.y);
    ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}
setup();
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Congrats on the first post!  A friendly hint, for JavaScript type questions, it's usually very helpful to create this on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), [plunker](https://plnkr.co/), or [insert favorite here], so you can share this, and we can actually play with your code.

Comment: I actually did make this on jsfiddle. Here is the link. https://jsfiddle.net/Phers/mLdpqax8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

Instead of making the ball a kind of static object I made a constructor function ([More about that here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_constructors.asp)).

Then I made a ball array to store all the balls.

To make the dragging possible I store a seperate ball, which is not being moved by "physics" in the `newBall` variable. This ball is either invisible or is the ball currently being dragged.

In `mouseDown()` the `newBall` gets positioned under the cursor.
In `mouseUp()` it gets it's velocity and gets added to the array of animated `balls`. Also a new `newBall` gets created.

In `loop()` I loop two times through the array of animated `balls`. Once for the physics, once for the painting.
(Normally you would use two different methods with different tickRates to make animation more smooth, because physics calculation doesn't need to happen 60 times per second.

```js
var width = 400;
var height = 400;
var canvas = ctx = false;
var frameRate = 1 / 60; // Seconds
var frameDelay = frameRate * 1000; // ms
var loopTimer = false;

function ball() {
  this.position = {
    x: width / 2,
    y: height / 2
  };
  this.velocity = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  };
  this.radius = 15; // 1px = 1cm
  this.restitution = -1
};
var balls = [];
var newBall = new ball();


var mouse = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  isDown: false
};

function getMousePosition(event) {
  mouse.x = event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  mouse.y = event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
}

var mouseDown = function(event) {
  if (event.which == 1) {
    getMousePosition(event);
    mouse.isDown = true;
    newBall.position.x = mouse.x;
    newBall.position.y = mouse.y;
  }
}
var mouseUp = function(event) {
  if (event.which == 1) {
    mouse.isDown = false;
    newBall.velocity.y = (newBall.position.y - mouse.y) / 10;
    newBall.velocity.x = (newBall.position.x - mouse.x) / 10;
    balls.push(newBall);
    newBall = new ball();
  }
}
var setup = function() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.onmousemove = getMousePosition;
  canvas.onmousedown = mouseDown;
  canvas.onmouseup = mouseUp;
  ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
  loopTimer = setInterval(loop, frameDelay);
}
var loop = function() {
  for (var ball of balls) {
    ball.position.x += ball.velocity.x * frameRate * 100;
    ball.position.y += ball.velocity.y * frameRate * 100;

    if (ball.position.y > height - ball.radius) {
      ball.velocity.y *= ball.restitution;
      ball.position.y = height - ball.radius;
    }
    if (ball.position.x > width - ball.radius) {
      ball.velocity.x *= ball.restitution;
      ball.position.x = width - ball.radius;
    }
    if (ball.position.x < ball.radius) {
      ball.velocity.x *= ball.restitution;
      ball.position.x = ball.radius;
    }
    if (ball.position.y < ball.radius) {
      ball.velocity.y *= ball.restitution;
      ball.position.y = ball.radius;
    }
  }
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  for (var ball of balls) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(ball.position.x, ball.position.y);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0, 0, ball.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.restore();
  }

  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(newBall.position.x, newBall.position.y);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, newBall.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.restore();

  if (mouse.isDown) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(newBall.position.x, newBall.position.y);
    ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}
setup();
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Now to get a bit more complex:

I added `tickDelay` and `tickTimer` to use them in a tickLoop

The `ball` constructor now has two methods:

`show()` draws the ball on the canvas

`tick()` does the pysics stuff (`dt`= deltaTime: time since last tick)

`newBall` is now `null` if the mouse isn't pressed

`setup()` initializes the `width` and `height` according to the `<canvas>` elements real size

`tick()` loops through the balls and calls `.tick()` tickDelay is in milliseconds so it gets divided by 1000

`drawFrame()` is your former `loop()` and does the drawing stuff

```js
var width = 400;
var height = 400;
var canvas = ctx = false;
var frameRate = 1 / 60; // Seconds
var frameDelay = frameRate * 1000; // ms
var tickDelay = frameDelay * 2; //ticks 2 times slower than frames
var frameTimer;
var tickTimer;

function ball() {
  this.position = {
    x: width / 2,
    y: height / 2
  };
  this.velocity = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  };
  this.radius = 15; // 1px = 1cm
  this.restitution = -.99;
  this.show = function() {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(this.position.x, this.position.y);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0, 0, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.restore();
  };
  this.tick = function(dt) {
    this.position.x += this.velocity.x * dt;
    this.position.y += this.velocity.y * dt;

    if (this.position.y > height - this.radius) {
      this.velocity.y *= this.restitution;
      this.position.y = height - this.radius;
    }
    if (this.position.x > width - this.radius) {
      this.velocity.x *= this.restitution;
      this.position.x = width - this.radius;
    }
    if (this.position.x < this.radius) {
      this.velocity.x *= this.restitution;
      this.position.x = this.radius;
    }
    if (this.position.y < this.radius) {
      this.velocity.y *= this.restitution;
      this.position.y = this.radius;
    }
  }
};
var balls = [];
var newBall;


var mouse = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  isDown: false
};

function getMousePosition(event) {
  mouse.x = event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  mouse.y = event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
}

function mouseDown(event) {
  if (event.which == 1) {
    getMousePosition(event);
    mouse.isDown = true;
    if (!newBall) newBall = new ball();
    newBall.position.x = mouse.x;
    newBall.position.y = mouse.y;
  }
}

function mouseUp(event) {
  if (event.which == 1) {
    mouse.isDown = false;
    newBall.velocity.y = (newBall.position.y - mouse.y);
    newBall.velocity.x = (newBall.position.x - mouse.x);
    balls.push(newBall);
    newBall = null;
  }
}

function setup() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  width = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  height = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.onmousemove = getMousePosition;
  canvas.onmousedown = mouseDown;
  canvas.onmouseup = mouseUp;
  ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
  requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);
  frameTimer = setInterval(drawFrame, frameDelay);
  tickTimer = setInterval(tick, tickDelay);
}

function tick() {
  for (var ball of balls) ball.tick(tickDelay * .001);
}

function drawFrame() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  for (var ball of balls) ball.show();
  if (newBall) newBall.show(ctx);

  if (mouse.isDown && newBall) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(newBall.position.x, newBall.position.y);
    ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}
setup();
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

A really simple way would to do exactly the same as you do now, but not initiate all functions as a variable. Change all the variables that are functions to just functions, and where you call them. At least the variable called ball. Then after that you could make two variables like this

```
ball1 = new ball();
ball2 = new ball();
```

Your script is kind of messy so hard for me to say if this will go through without any errors, but if it does, I am more than happy to help. This is not the very best solution if you only go for the way i presented now so please do not use this as you solution, but more as a way to get started. Also you will not really learn anything of it if we just gave you the answer

Edit:

Another thing to mark is that using setInterval for games and graphical projects may be a bad idea since JavaScript is single threaded. A better solution is using `requestAnimationFrame()`

It would look something like this

```
function mainLoop() {
update();
draw();
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}

// Start things off
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
```

Comment: I'm still relatively new to javascript. Do you think you could elaborate on what it means when your do"for (var ball of balls)"

Comment: I think you meant my answer: `for..of` loops through an array and stores the value of each iteration in the variable before the `of`

Comment: I am doing the same as the other answers. Only not using the array. You create variables that are equal to the function your current ball variable equals to. If you only want two balls, I do not see the reason for creating an array @PhersTheFirst

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel yes I meant something like yours just not using an array when he only wants two balls, better to not over complicate things when you are starting off. Your answer is way more detailed so if I were him I would look at your answer and develop it into a non array one

Comment: Thank you, both of you, this was very helpful.